# Why do two different quaternions appear to have the same rotation?

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions

When using a Quaternions I've noticed something I don't quite understand.

If I'm rotation $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians on the Y axis it goes from $[0,0,0,1]$ to $[0,\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{2}]$. A rotation of $\pi$ radians is $[0,1,0,0]$. A rotation of $\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ is $[0,\sqrt{2},0,-\sqrt{2}]$. A full rotation comes out to be $[0,0,0,-1]$, which, for some reason, appears to be indifferent from the $[0,0,0,1]$ quaternion I've started out with.

But if I rotate it the other way, the y axis grows "negatively". That is to say, a rotation of $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ comes out to be $[0,-\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{2}]$, different from the one I get with a rotation of $\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, yet acts exactly the same.

Why are there two rotations that appear to be the same thing?

Comment: The quaternions $q$ and $-q$ represent the same rotation.

Comment: @Rahul Why is that?

Comment: Because rotating by $\theta$ about the axis $u$ is the same as rotating by $-\theta$ about $-u$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

A rotation of angle $2\theta$ around an axis oriented by the versor $\mathbf{u}$ ( with $|\mathbf{u}|=1$) is represented by the quaternion:
$$
\cos \theta +\mathbf{u}\sin \theta
$$

if we change:
$$
\theta \rightarrow - \theta \qquad \mathbf{u} \rightarrow - \mathbf{u}
$$

we have

$$
\cos (-\theta)-\mathbf{u}\sin (-\theta)= \cos \theta +\mathbf{u}\sin \theta
$$